# How to upgrade JBoss EAP 6.4 to 7.0 in ubuntu without loseing data. (Zip installation)

Tags: ubuntu, jboss, upgrade

How to upgrade JBoss EAP 6.4 to 7.0 without losing data that is installed from ZIP archive? I Have only one instance with some defined users and web apps? Which directories should I replace or may should I apply some patches?
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Take a look in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/migration_guide/ and maybe this tool can be useful https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-server-migration/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved that task with [wildfly-server-migration](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-server-migration/releases) it works pretty nice. 
Just follow their guide from main page of project.

It's something like that:

```
sudo jboss-server-migration/server-migration.sh --source /opt/jboss-eap-6.4/ --target /opt/jboss-eap-7.0/
```

and just select your answers between 'yes' or 'no'